# bike won't start until rider wear helmet

Tags: arduino, rf

I am trying to make a project in which ignition system of bike will not start until the rider would wear a helmet.

This can be done through RF Transmitter and receiver, but how it will be achieved? I am confuse about that.

Comment: Have a look at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's best to offer design attempts for criticism here, rather than to throw out ideas like this.  Do you have some designs?

Answer (score 5):

Break it up in steps:

1. Helmet should 'know' when the rider has the helmet on
2. Bike should 'know' when the rider has the helmet on

The first can be achieved in many ways (proximity sensor, LDR, temperature?); but this is out of scope for your question.

For the ignition there can also be multiple solutions, like:

1. If the helmet knows that it is worn, it can send a message via RF to the bike. If the helmet is taken off, it also needs to send this to the bike. The bike knows at all times if the helmet is worn.
2. When the user tries the ignition, the bike requests from the helmet the current status. If worn, it starts.

The second is better, because it involves less communication, but is also safer (what if the helmet is taken on/off outside the RF range for example).

Note that this is not fool proof, so it only works if the rider is 'cooperative'... If it should be fool proof, use a much better way to detect if the helmet is worn; some problems to be fixed:

- What if the helmet is worn not by the rider but someone else?
- The sensors used to detect the helmet is worn should be fool proof
- What if there are multiple bikes/helmet in the vicinity? How does the bike knows which helmet belongs to the rider on the bike to be started?
- ...

Comment: Querying the helmet is somewhat problematic because it tends to mean needing to keep a radio receiver always on in the helmet (at least when worn) to listen for queries.  It's typically a lot more power efficient to just send a status broadcast every second while the helmet is on, and if you want a two-way handshake have that triggered by the helmet's transmission for a receive window shortly following it.  Otherwise you're likely to end up needing to establish clock synchronization so that you can have windows for unsolicited bike to helmet transmissions.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I thought that most RF's can wakeup a microcontroller, but indeed, the RF should be on. So your solution works better energy wise. There might be a problem if the helmet thinks it's on (like if it is in a dark closet, and using a LDR sensor. So in your case a better mechanism should be in place for detecting what means 'worn'.

Comment: A periodic short range radio *transmission* can quite easily cost less power than the sensor you'd use to detect being worn, unless it's something truly passive.   An LDR probably won't cut it.  A modulated light emitter/detector pair could perhaps work if only operated for a brief instant on the same cycle - while (1) {measure(); transmit(); sleep();}

Comment: You mean a light on the bike and a detector on the helmet or vice versa? That sounds interesting.

Comment: No, a light emitter-detector pair across the inside of the helmet.  Or a capacitance sensor, etc.  Many things that might work will require some power to operate, so they may have to only measure periodically.  But as has been pointed out, you don't want to shut the bike down quickly anyway, but only with a lot of notice and time (and maybe even not at all).

Comment: Have you considered what will happen if you are riding and remove the helmet? will the bike just stop? Good start for an accident....

Comment: @SolarMike ... that why I put the ... at the end, there are plenty of cases where more thought is needed. Probably you need a controlled stop instead of an abrupt stop. You also don't want to be able to continue, otherwise a rider takes off its helmet after ignition (if he doesn't like a helmet). There are plenty of other  cases (what if the battery is empty, how to check the sensors are ok, what about a second person on the bike and so on.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers sorry, really directed at OP , but yes does start off a good set of questions.. cheers.

Answer (score 3):

I will answer both as a bike rider as well as an Electronics Engineer.

As a rider when I want to go out for a ride, the first thing I do is to get the key in the ignition, start the bike and let the engine warm up while I get myself ready to ride. Those actions include close jacket, start the bluetooth headset, get helmet on, and put gloves on.
The way I see it, if I had to sit there  and wait for the engine to warm up, while wearing all of the gear, that would be a product that I would never buy.

As an electronics engineer, thankfully I can see other options. Most modern bikes are already fitted with a safety system, that kills the engine if you try to engage the first gear while the foot stand is lowered. A similar kill switch could be added to the system is the helmet is not on, and the rider tries to ride away.

I would use a wireless method of communication, either Bluetooth, maybe integrated with the helmet's headset, or any other wireless protocol.
As other have mentioned there are plenty of ways of detecting if the helmet is actually worn, LED, switches, or even capacitive measurement. Choose whatever works for you.

Comment: +1, you are absolute right about the motorbike start procedure. The helmet goes on last, so you can hear if the bike has some ache.

Comment: In some countries what you do is forbidden by law (letting the engine run just to warm up), so the helmet would be helping you to respect that law.

Answer (score 1):

The modern solution to everything- use a rear-facing webcam on the handlebars and a bit of AI running on something like a Raspberry Pi to detect a helmet on the head of a human rider. This could be combined with a front-facing "dashcam".

Of course the rider could probably fool such a system with a papier-mâché fake helmet (or some unapproved helmet-shaped thing), but if you consider that the main reason riders would avoid the helmet is comfort this would probably incentivize all but the reprobates.

You should disengage the ignition cutoff system immediately under any conditions that would represent motion (perhaps putting the bike into gear)- you certain don't want the "safety" device accidentally cutting the ignition when the biker is trying to overtake a truck/lorry with oncoming traffic. There are probably other safety-related considerations that a system engineer would incorporate into the design.